# lambda functions for pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| IDX | PROP_ID | YEAR | CATEGORY | CATEGORY_DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1987 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1001 | 1987 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1002 | 1990 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 1002 | 1990 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1002 | 1990 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 1002 | 1990 | 3 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to groupby `PROP_ID` and for each "group" of `PROP_ID`, I would like to find out if the `CATEGORY_DIFF` is NOT EQUAL to 0 (i.e. if the CATEGORY_DIFF is either more than 0 or less than 0). I'm thinking of applying a custom lambda function to do this :

```
df_prop_id = df.groupby('PROP_ID')['CATEGORY_DIFF'].apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
```

But I keep getting an error. Appreciate help.

EDIT:
For each unique PROP_ID series, I only want to compute the diff between the first and second values:
Expected answer:

| PROP_ID | X[1] - X[0] |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1002 | 0 |

Comment: Can you add your expected output to the question ?

Comment: df_prop_id = df.groupby('PROP_ID')['CATEGORY_DIFF'].any()`?

Comment: Try `df.groupby('PROP_ID')['CATEGORY_DIFF'].apply(lambda x: x.iat[1] - x.iat[0])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IDX': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    'PROP_ID': [1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002],
    'YEAR': [1987, 1987, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990],
    'CATEGORY': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3],
    'CATEGORY_DIFF': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
})
```

Sort and group data so we can easily calculate the differences in the next step:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['PROP_ID', 'CATEGORY'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('PROP_ID')
```

Go through each PROP_ID, calculate the differences, and store them in the new dataframe `final_df`:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PROP_ID', 'X[1] - X[0]'])

for group_name, group_df in df_grouped:
    diff = group_df['CATEGORY_DIFF'].iloc[1] - group_df['CATEGORY_DIFF'].iloc[0]
    final_df = final_df.append({'PROP_ID': group_name, 'X[1] - X[0]': diff}, ignore_index=True)
```

Show final data with desired output:

```
final_df
```